# WiFi range: How far do the different standards go?

Tags: wireless-networking

Comparing wireless a,b,g,N: is there a noticeable difference in the coverage area provided by each of the different standards?  Do any of them do a better job penetrating different kinds of walls (namely concrete block)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Protocols) has a table of the various protocols and their approximate ranges.

- **A** - indoor 35m (outdoor 120m)
- **B** - indoor 38m (outdoor 140m)
- **G** - indoor 38m (outdoor 140m)
- **N** - indoor ~70m (outdoor ~250m)

There is very little difference between A, B and G and it is likely that you will find transmitter/receiver quality will play a far bigger role in the range you can actually achieve.

N however, specifically added features that increased the potential range - [see this article](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3680781)